# Jquery Append Not working; "Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters ..." error were thrown at F12

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append an HTML code using Jquery. f12 throws an error saying that < and new lines were deprecated.

I've already checked if my Jquery syntax had errors within. Here's the Jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#perGroup_add").click(function(){
  $("#perGroup_container").append("<div class='form-group row'> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Size' required> </div> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Price/Consumable' required> </div> <div> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a> </div> </div>");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr class="sidebar-divider">
            <div id="perGroup_container">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        Per Group
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <a href="update_stud.php<?php echo '?$id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                            <span id="perGroup_add" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add More Row
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Size" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Price/Consumable" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="del_stud.php<?php echo '?$id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

The Jquery function should create another row of input boxes + delete buttons.
the f12 error shows me this

```
[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using this quotation `` because this can contain both inline and multi-line text while this quotation **""** only can keep inline-text or text which is not too big compared to the text you are trying to append.

I am using jquery `-version 3+` and this code works fine for me as I do the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#perGroup_add").click(function(){
        $("#perGroup_container").append(`<div class='form-group row'> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Size' required> </div> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Price/Consumable' required> </div> <div> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a> </div> </div>`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found your problem.

Take a look, it's your `html markup` problem. You've write a `click` function on a `span` where your `click` is only triggering anchor.

Set `id` to the anchor and write a click funtion for that.

Here I've written that for you in the `code snippet`. I've added `e.preventDefault()` to stop your default `href` call of the anchor.

Take a look, see if it's worthy

```js
var html = "<div class='form-group row'> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Size' required> </div> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Price/Consumable' required> </div> <div> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a> </div> </div>";
                
$("#perGroup_add").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#perGroup_container").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="perGroup_container">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    Per Group
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <a href="update_stud.php<?php echo '?$id='.$id; ?>" id="perGroup_add" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add More Row
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Size" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Price/Consumable" required>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="del_stud.php<?php echo '?$id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrap  with `<a>` and  it is trying to redirect, replace it with  tag and append will work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#perGroup_add").click(function(){
  $("#perGroup_container").append("<div class='form-group row'> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Size' required> </div> <div class='col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0'> <input type='text' name='packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data' class='form-control form-control-user' placeholder='Package Price/Consumable' required> </div> <div> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'> <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'> </i> </a> </div> </div>");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr class="sidebar-divider">
            <div id="perGroup_container">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        Per Group
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                           <button id="perGroup_add" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">Add More Row</button> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Size" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <input type="text" name="packres_categories_paxgroup_consumable_data" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Package Price/Consumable" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="del_stud.php<?php echo '?$id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```